# Visualize mathematical functions

Tags: actionscript-3, function, plot, tween

I want to make something like [this visualizer](http://www.greensock.com/roughease/). How is it possible to plot function like that? [Robert Penner](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/easing_demo.html) also did the same thing, or is that just an image?

Is this possible using only the `Graphics` class?

Any link or information will be useful.

Comment: You should study mathematics and function graphs a little. Because the answer to your question is trivial if you know a bit of how functions are plotted, but it takes a lot of effort to explain the basic knowledge of the subject in stackoverflow's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can plot that function over time by assigning it to any property. Some easing libraries let you assign to any number, others have to be set up with predefine properties based on the object (like the x position)

If you set up a tween for a movie clip, and tween x linearly `linear.EaseNone` from 0 to 100, and the y is using any of your other tween functions from 0 to 100, you will have the location animated. Then create a onEnterFrame listener, and every frame draw a line from the previous location to the current.